# Apache Camel - GSON JsonSerializer use on routes

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, gson, dsl

I have a endpoint with Camel that returns properties as JSON but are not with the proper order. The return class has a superclass that returns some control data which is necessarily to be present in every return.

```
public class Respuesta implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("subject")
    @Expose
    private String subject;

    @SerializedName("action")
    @Expose
    private String action;

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
...getter/setter
```

And the final return class inherits that piece.

```
public class FacturadoresListarResponse extends Respuesta implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("lst")
    @Expose
    private List<Facturador> listaProveedores;

    public FacturadoresListarResponse(List<Facturador> listaProveedores) {
        super();
        this.listaProveedores = listaProveedores;
    }

    public FacturadoresListarResponse() {

    }

    public void setRespuesta(Respuesta rsp) {
        super.setAction(rsp.getAction());
        super.setDescription(rsp.getDescription());
        super.setStatus(rsp.getStatus());
        super.setSubject(rsp.getSubject());
    }

   getter/setter...
}
```

So, the Gson's Marshaller takes first the inherited class property (lst), and then the parent class properties (subject, status, etc.), giving this kind of result on the wire.

```
{
  "lst": [
    {
      "rut": "XXXX-X",
      "rzsoc": "XXXXXXx",
      "res": 1,
      "ema": "a@a.cl"
    }
  ],
  "subject": "facturadores",
  "action": "listar",
  "status": 0,
  "description": "OK"
}
```

I wrote a GSON custom JsonSerializer that builds data in order, but I can't use in a Camel DSL syntax. I tried, but without results:

```
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson,FacturadoresListarRspSerializer.class, true)
.convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
```

Is there supported by Camel to use these kind of serializers to achieve proper order without migrating to Jackson?

Note: The code of the serializer (FacturadoresListarRspSerializer.class).

```
public class FacturadoresListarRspSerializer implements JsonSerializer<FacturadoresListarResponse> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(FacturadoresListarResponse src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("subject", src.getSubject());
        jsonObject.addProperty("action", src.getAction());
        jsonObject.addProperty("status", src.getStatus());
        jsonObject.addProperty("description", src.getDescription());

        final JsonArray jsarrFacturadores = new JsonArray();
        for (final Facturador fact : src.getListaProveedores()) {
           JsonObject jsobFacturadores = new JsonObject();
           jsobFacturadores.addProperty("rut", fact.getRutCompleto());
           jsobFacturadores.addProperty("rzsoc", fact.getRazonSocial());
           jsobFacturadores.addProperty("res", fact.getResolucion());
           jsobFacturadores.addProperty("ema", fact.getCorreoEnvio());
           jsarrFacturadores.add(jsobFacturadores);
        }
        jsonObject.add("lst", jsarrFacturadores);

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new GSON instance:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(FacturadoresListarResponse.class, 
        new FacturadoresListarRspSerializer()).create();
```

Create a new `GsonDataFormat` by specifying the previously created `Gson` instance:

```
GsonDataFormat gsonDataFormat = new GsonDataFormat(gson, FacturadoresListarResponse.class);
```

Specify the previous data format in your `RouteBuilder`'s `marshal(DataFormat dataFormat)` method:

```
.marshal(gsonDataFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked giving the expected response in the proper order.